# angular-ui-tab-scroll: Weird spacing beetwen block to tabs included separetely

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, tabs

First of all, thanks for this great library!

Now, i am facing a weird problem when wrapping a **tabset** with tabs included separately, ie either via
single **tab** elements added manually in the DOM, either via group of tab added by use of  **ng-repeat**:

[image]

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aloZvFN65owbTWf0AsW5?p=preview):

```
      <scrollable-tabset show-tooltips="false">
        <tabset>
          <!-- 1st Block of tabs-->
          <tab>
              <tab-heading>Tab 0</tab-heading>
              Tab 0 content
          </tab>
           <!-- 2nd Block of tabs-->
          <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs1" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
            <tab-heading>{{tab.heading}}</tab-heading>
            {{tab.content}}
          </tab>
          <!-- 3rd Block of tabs-->
          <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs2" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
            <tab-heading>{{tab.heading}}</tab-heading>
            {{tab.content}}
          </tab>
           <!-- 4th Block of tabs-->
          <tab>
              <tab-heading>Tab 6</tab-heading>
              Tab 0 content
          </tab>
        </tabset>
      </scrollable-tabset>
```

I inspected/compared the css of each block, but there is no difference...

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using `inline-block`. A series of inline-block elements formatted like you normally format HTML will have spaces in between them.

To solve this you should use `float`, or reformat you html to not have spaces between elements. I recommend you use `float`.

[Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Thanks Stefan! You've made my day!  in my case, adding **margin-right:-4px;** to the **.ui-tabs-scrollable .nav > li** (from angular-ui-tab-scroll.css) indeed did the trick.

Comment: I've submitted [PR#4](https://github.com/VersifitTechnologies/angular-ui-tab-scroll/pull/4) and it has been accepted and merged. So this fix will be available on next release (i.e > v0.10 )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as efan Dimov said it can be resolved by using the float CSS property. You can also achieve the same non-spaced result by changing the whitespace in your markup like so:

http://plnkr.co/edit/FMf21S8ellpXTOawHgN2?p=preview

```
 <scrollable-tabset show-tooltips="false">
        <tabset><!-- 1st Block of tabs--><tab>
              <tab-heading>Tab 0</tab-heading>
              Tab 0 content
          </tab><!-- 2nd Block of tabs--><tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs1" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
            <tab-heading>{{tab.heading}}</tab-heading>
            {{tab.content}}
          </tab><!-- 3rd Block of tabs-->
          <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs2" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled"><tab-heading>{{tab.heading}}</tab-heading>
            {{tab.content}}</tab><!-- 4th Block of tabs--><tab><tab-heading>Tab 6</tab-heading>
              Tab 0 content</tab></tabset>
      </scrollable-tabset>
```

Here is a codepen by @chriscoyier that demonstrates each way to circumvent this issue: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/hmlqF